# How to deploy a parent image from Docker Hub into Artifactory Pro?

Tags: docker, artifactory, dockerhub

Our company is planning to block Docker hub in our network and to use our on prem Artifactory Pro as our docker registry. I got tasked to change all the Dockerfiles which uses a parent image from Docker hub (eg. FROM 9.0.20-jdk11-slim ...) into artifactory versions of those images.

eg:

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.20-jdk11-slim
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y nginx && \
    apt-get install -y python3 && \
    apt-get -y install ant
CMD ["ant"]
```

I already downloaded the images needed.. 
eg:

```
docker pull tomcat:9.0.20-jdk11-slim
docker save tomcat:9.0.20-jdk11-slim > tomcatjdk11_slim.tar
```

how do I make these available in Artifactory Pro so I could change the Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/), I copy some main idea from official document.

I guess for your case, `Artifactory Pro` as your docker registry already there, so no need to new one(STEP 1), then, you just need to push the image from dockerhub to your new local registry.

**1. Run a local registry**

```
$ docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

**2. Copy an image from Docker Hub to your registry**

```
$ docker pull ubuntu:16.04
$ docker tag ubuntu:16.04 localhost:5000/my-ubuntu
$ docker push localhost:5000/my-ubuntu
$ docker image remove ubuntu:16.04
$ docker image remove localhost:5000/my-ubuntu
$ docker pull localhost:5000/my-ubuntu
```

Comment: so i just replace the url with our artifactory installation? eg. docker tag 
ubuntu:16.04 https://artifactory.ca.blahblah.com:443/af-docker/my-ubuntu

Comment: Yes, I think so. Your artifactory just one kind of private docker registry.

Comment: I'm always getting an error during the docker login, im not sure if its correctly being called or it is persmissions that are lacking, i only have a BUILDUSER role:Get https://af-docker.artifactory.ph.blah.com/v2/: Bad Gateway

Answer (score 2):

Artifactory Pro(On Prem) is a repository manager supporting many kinds of technology or software.

Before pushing or pulling you need to create a repo in aritfactory of docker type that will act as your docker registry where you can push/pull images
[artifactory docker registry setup](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Registry)

Once the setup is done you need to pass the registry url of the created repo with docker commands to push/pull from private repo.